# Angular NGRX RXJS - Subscription to other observables inside effects don't work

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an issue, I have a service to manage SSE and I write this service:

```
    getAllNotify(url: string): Observable<EventDTO> {
      return new Observable(observer => {
        const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);

        eventSource.onopen = function () {
          console.log('connection for all data is established');
        };
        eventSource.onmessage = event => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            if (eventSource.readyState !== 0) {
              observer.next(JSON.parse(event.data));
            }
          });
        };
        eventSource.onerror = error => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            observer.error(error);
          });
        };
      });
    }

    private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
      return new EventSource(url);
    }
```

In the `app-Component` I dispatch an action to start the SSE connection that is listened by the effect below.

Inside this effects I need to get the response from the server and after that I need to subscribe to other observable in my ngrx store.

I'm trying to do it with `withLatestFrom` operator, but it works only for the first time; The server continues to send data, the service works but I have no response from the effect. If I remove the `withLatestFrom` operator I solve all the issues, it works correctly, but I need to subscribe to other observables to do some check inside the function. What am I wrong? I can't use other RXJS operators inside the effects?

```
  loadEVents3$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType('[Websocketevent] Load Websocketevents'),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.webSocketEventsService.getAllNotify(`${environment.SERVER_API_URL}/services/my-api-events/api/event`).pipe(
          map(res => {
            this.eventDto = res;
          }),
          withLatestFrom(
            this.idAccountSelector$,
            this.idCompanySelector$,
          ),
          map(res => {
            let idAccount = res[0];
            let idCompany = res[1];

            if (this.eventDto.eventType === EventType.FOLDER_NOTE) {
              if (this.eventDto.operationType === OperationType.CREATE) {
                return { type: noteEventsActions.ActionNotesType.LOAD_WEB_SOCKET_EVENTS_NOTES, payload: this.eventDto };
              } else if (this.eventDto.operationType === OperationType.UPDATE) {
                return { type: noteEventsActions.ActionNotesType.UPDATE_WEB_SOCKET_EVENTS_NOTES, payload: this.eventDto };
              } else if (this.eventDto.operationType === OperationType.DELETE) {
                return { type: noteEventsActions.ActionNotesType.DELETE_WEB_SOCKET_EVENTS_NOTES, payload: this.eventDto };
              }
            }
  
          }),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to do it with withLatestFrom operator, but it works only for the first time.

I'm surprised what you've written works even the first time. I think it shouldn't.

#### A minor problem:

```ts
map(res => {
  this.eventDto = res;
}),
```

As far as RxJS is concerned,

```ts
map(_ => {})
```

doesn't have well defined behavior. It will transform *(map)* every response into `undefined`. This is probably not what you want. Maybe the `tap` operator would be better. There you can create a side effect without modifying the stream.

The map and the tap below are roughly equivalent:

```ts
map(res => {
  this.eventDto = res;
  return res;
})

tap(res => {
  this.eventDto = res;
})
```

Your second map operator also doesn't always have a return result. You'll see the same problem there.

---

#### A major problem:

`withLatestFrom` augments the source stream.

Consider this settup that is a bit similar to yours

```
interval(7000).pipe(

  withLatestFrom(
    interval(5000),
    interval(3000)
  ),
  map(vs => vs.map(v => v + 1))

).subscribe(([i7s, i5s, i3s]) => {
  console.log(`Source Interval has emitted ${i7s} times`);
  console.log(`withLatestFrom 5 second Interval has emitted ${i5s} times`);
  console.log(`withLatestFrom 3 second Interval has emitted ${i3s} times`);
});
```

Notice how map and subscribe both get a thruple (a 3-value array)?

Your code is assigning the wrong variables to the wrong part of the result. `let idAccount = res[0];` should always be undefined. So, that should throw an error and then you'll ignore that error and the whole process will stop.

Which is probably what you're seeing? Hard to say.

#### Toward a solution:

You didn't give us a minimal working example, so any solution I propose (using your code) is a solution I can't really test. Even so! Perhaps try something like this:

```ts
loadEVents3$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Websocketevent] Load Websocketevents'),
    mergeMap(() => this.webSocketEventsService.getAllNotify(
        `${environment.SERVER_API_URL}/services/my-api-events/api/event`
      ).pipe(
        tap(res => this.eventDto = res),
        filter(eventDto => eventDto.eventType === EventType.FOLDER_NOTE),
        withLatestFrom(
          this.idAccountSelector$,
          this.idCompanySelector$,
        ),
        map(([eventDto, idAccount, idCompany]) => {

          // Because of the filter above, we KNOW that
          // eventDto.eventType === EventType.FOLDER_NOTE is true here.

          let type = null;

          if (eventDto.operationType === OperationType.CREATE) {
            type = noteEventsActions.ActionNotesType.LOAD_WEB_SOCKET_EVENTS_NOTES;
          } else if (eventDto.operationType === OperationType.UPDATE) {
            type = noteEventsActions.ActionNotesType.UPDATE_WEB_SOCKET_EVENTS_NOTES;
          } else if (this.eventDto.operationType === OperationType.DELETE) { 
            type = noteEventsActions.ActionNotesType.DELETE_WEB_SOCKET_EVENTS_NOTES;
          }

          // Looks like you never use idAccount or idCompany???
          
          return {
            type,
            payload: eventDto 
          };

        }),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )
    )
  )
);
```